# elasticsearch null_value replacement not working for integers

Tags: elasticsearch

i have the following in my mapping. The id can be null sometimes so i am using null_value : 1.

```
 "Id" : {
        "type" : "integer",
        "store" : true,
        "doc_values" : true,
        "null_value" : 1,
        "index":"not_analyzed"
},
```

when I try to add documents to the index, I am still getting parse error. How can I fix this?

```
[2017-12-24 10:42:42,601][DEBUG][action.bulk              ][test-2017-12-24]
[7] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[test-2017-12-24][test]
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [Id]
    at 

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at 
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Comment: Which ES version?

Comment: From [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) it looks like you need something like `"null_value": "NULL"` in mapping. Why do you set null value to 1?

Comment: Only string data types can have "NULL" not integers.

Answer (score 1):

From the error you can see that you try to index the string `"null"` in the Id field, which it cannot parse into a (nullable) integer. Try putting in `null` (without quotes)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Such a simple thing , but very difficult to pinpoint answer.